# Specify input ports with NetGraph for network within a network

Tags: graphs-and-networks, neural-networks

I have a network with two input ports ("a" and "b").
I want to use this net within a bigger network. The problem is that I cannot find a syntax to specify to which input port the previous layers of the outer network should connect.

To do an example. My internal net can be defined as

```
net1 = NetGraph[
 {
   "2x" -> ElementwiseLayer[(2*#) &],
   "sum" -> ThreadingLayer[(#1 + #2) &]
   },
  {
   NetPort["a"] -> "2x" -> "sum",
   NetPort["b"] -> "sum"
   }
  ]
```

I can easily pass the inputs to this net doing

```
net1[<|"a" -> {1, 2, 3}, "b" -> {10, 20, 30}|>]
```

or

```
net1[<|"b" -> {10, 20, 30},"a" -> {1, 2, 3}|>]
```

both returns `{12., 24., 36.}`

I want now to place this net within another network. For example

```
net2 = NetGraph[
  {
   "A" -> PartLayer[1],
   "B" -> PartLayer[2],
   "net1" -> net1
   },
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> "A",
   NetPort["Input"] -> "B",
   {"A","B"} -> "net1"
   }
  ]
net2[{{1, 2, 3}, {10, 20, 30}}]
```

This would work, but it's not very robust, as the only thing telling net1 which input send to port "a" and "b" is just the order in which the input are passed.

I tried to do something like

```
{<|"b" -> "b", "a" -> "a"|>} -> "net1"
```

but this syntax is not accepted by NetGraph.
Is there any better syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer to be

```
net2 = NetGraph[
  {
   "a" -> PartLayer[1],
   "b" -> PartLayer[2],
   "net1" -> net1
   },
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> "a",
   NetPort["Input"] -> "b",
   "b" -> NetPort["net1", "b"],
   "a" -> NetPort["net1", "a"]
   }
  ]
```

Comment: I searched for this for ages, thanks! It should really be in the docs for `NetGraph` that subnetworks can be combined by specifying the `NetPort[subnet, portName]` that should be connected